# VB.NET: Multi Threaded GUI Updating

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have an windows form app with 4 datagridviews.  Each DGV is used to display fetched data from database.  The data is highly variable and can have thousands of rows.  Right now, each of the 4 DGVs has to fetch the data from the database, bind the datatable to the DGV, then autosize the columns.  Each of the 3 operations can be pretty slow (many seconds) for each DGV.  I am looking to break this up into as many threads as possible to speed up the GUI.

My initial thought was one thread per DGV, but I have read a lot of posts (and tested a few things) that makes me think I can only thread the DB queries, but as far as binding the DTs and autosizing the columns, there is nothing I can do because a separate thread cannot update the GUI.  Is that true?  Are there any clever ways to multi-thread updating the GUI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Don't load thousands of rows, but only rows you are going to display. 2. Database queries are IO(input-output) operations - check how to load data from database asynchronously without blocking UI and wasting threads. Notice that with asynchronous approach you can load rows for multiple datagridviews simultaneously ("in parallel")

Comment: Agreed on everything you say.  I actually warn the user if there are going to be more than 1k rows returned so they can add more search terms.  But often, they want to display all the results.  I can't control that.  I realize I can thread the DB queries, but what can I do about binding the DTs to DGVs and autosizing the DGV columns?

Comment: _But often, they want to display all the results_ - all results will not feet in the display :)

Comment: You can use other *threads* (possibly, making use of the `async/await` pattern, since it's usually available) to fetch the data: the UI thread will update/set the datasource of the bound controls. Possibly, get rid of the Autosizing part, that's really slow: set a predefined size to your columns. Use a BindingSource to bind a control to a datasource. You should work on the SQL side to fetch just as much as needed (paging the data or getting only updated records). Or, if that's not possible, use the DataGridView `VirtualMode`.